# PHP creating a string template for injecting string later

Tags: php

I'm creating an array of strings which represent a template of URI's which I latter want to use with different ids, and I use "%id" as a placeholder

```
$template = array()
$template[] = "/campaigns/%id/";
$template[] = "/campaigns/%id/pictures";
$template[] = "/campaigns/%id/likes";
```

Now i'm also setting an array of optional ids:

```
$ids = array("123","456","789");
```

I have a functions which checks if a given URI is valid.
This function will receive a URI and then will compare it to all the valid URI's according to the template and the ids I defined:

```
public function isUriAllowed($uri){
    $allowedUris = $this->getTemplateUris();
    foreach($this->ids as $id)
    {
        foreach($allowedUris as $allowedUri)
        {
            $allowedUri = str_replace($this->idPlaceHolder,$id,$allowedUri);
            if (strcmp($allowedUri,$uri) == 0)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have a gut feeling that there is a more elegant way to achieve what i'm trying to do, but i'm not sure how to do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Aside from building a big regex to match against, I can't see a nicer way to do this. This is probably the best-performing solution too. However, I will say for most routing implementations, you wouldn't want some big 'isvalid' type of function that both verifies that the route is well-formed and that it matches a route that exists. Better to build the routing to a particular id (eg in MVC would be passed to a controller), then have that check fail separately if the URL matches a route, but there's no ID available at that route.

Comment: It actually doesnt do route. It checks if the specific use is authorized to a specific route. Trying to build Scopes for endpoints.

Comment: Is this function going to be called multiple times within the same request?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for check the url:

```
$test_url = '/campaigns/123/pictures';
$ids_availables = array("123","456","789");

$valid = preg_match('/\/campaigns\/('.implode('|', $ids_availables).')\/(pictures|likes)?/', $test_url, $matches);
/* print (boolean) if $test_url is valid */
var_dump($valid);
/* if is a valid url, $matches is an array that contains campaing_id and pictures/likes values */
var_dump($matches);
```

edit: sorry, i'm edited for correct an error in the sintaxis.

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess, you are trying to create a kind of router??, let me share you the router I made a long long time ago.

```
class Router {
  private $request_uri;
  private $routes;
  private static $instance = false;

  const DEFAULT_CONTROLLER = "MyController";
  const DEFAULT_ACTION = "myAction";

  public static function get_instance() {
    if(!self::$instance) {
      $class = get_called_class();
      self::$instance = new $class();
    }
    return self::$instance;
  }

  protected function __construct() {
    list($this->request_uri) = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  }

  public function set_route($route, $target = [], $condition = []) {
    $url_regex = preg_replace_callback('@:[\w]+@', function($matches) use ($condition) {
      $res = '([a-zA-Z0-9_\+\-%]+)';
      $key = str_replace(':', '', $matches[0]);
      if(array_key_exists($key, $condition)) $res = '('.$condition[$key].')';
      return $res;
    }, $route);
    preg_match_all('@:([\w]+)@', $route, $keys, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    $this->routes[$route] = ['regex' => $url_regex .'/?', 'target' => $target, 'keys' => $keys[0]];
  }

  public function run() {
    $params = [];
    foreach($this->routes as $v) {
      if(preg_match('@^'.$v['regex'].'$@', $this->request_uri, $values)) {
        if(isset($v['target']['controller'])) $controller = $v['target']['controller'];
        if(isset($v['target']['action'])) $action =  $v['target']['action'];
        for($i = count($values) -1; $i--;) {
          $params[substr($v['keys'][$i], 1)] = $values[$i +1];
        }
        break;
      }
    }

    $controller = isset($controller) ? $controller : self::DEFAULT_CONTROLLER;
    $action = isset($action) ? $action : self::DEFAULT_ACTION;
    $redirect = new $controller();
    $redirect->{$action}(array_merge($params, $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE));
  }
}
```

HOW TO USE IT:

```
require_once 'Router.php';

$router = Router::get_instance();
$router->set_route("/");
$router->set_route("/nocontroller/noaction", ['controller' => 'NoController']);
$router->set_route("/nocontroller/nocontroller", ['action' => 'without']);
$router->set_route("/another/echoes/:param", ['controller' => 'Another', 'action' => 'echoes'], ['param' => '[a-z]{3}']);
$router->set_route("/another/echoes/:param/:id", ['controller' => 'Another', 'action' => 'dump'], ['param' => '[a-z]{3}', 'id' => '[\d]{1,8}']);
$router->set_route("/another/echoes/:param/some/:id", ['controller' => 'Another', 'action' => 'dump'], ['param' => '[a-z]{3}', 'id' => '[\d]{1,8}']);
$router->set_route("/another/echoes/:param/some/:id/:more", ['controller' => 'Another', 'action' => 'dump'], ['param' => '[a-z]{3}', 'id' => '[\d]{1,8}']);
$router->run();
```

Ok, you need to use an autoloader... if you want it one just ask for it :p, or jsut make a require for every controller you are going to use.

If that not the case, my apologies. After all, you have your answer in my code too. ENJOY IT!!

Comment: I read you are not trying to do a router, but you want to check if the url is valid for a specific use, and with the params you previously defined. My router can acomplish what you want, just pass to set_route the third param to define what params you allow in which placeholder, and instead call a controller continue with your flow in the last four lines of code...